# Porque é que a tag:aplicação-web não é corretamente linkada?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, tags, tag-específica

A tag [aplicação-web](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-web) linka para uma tag não existente.

Contudo a [página da tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web/info) diz que existem 341 perguntas com a tag.

[Ao procurar perguntas com a tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-web) há 0 resultados...

A tag existe ou não existe? Existem ou não perguntas com esta tag?

Comment: Aqui aparece tudo ok. Clico no seu link e abre a listagem com 341 itens. Será que seu browser não está com codificação de acentuação travada em alguma específica?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema descrito, veja: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XWKq.gif

Comment: @Bacco a [Remocao da tag](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2389/remover-tags-web-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-web-e-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-desktop?rq=1) está a ser debatida também...

Comment: Testei no FF, IE e no Opera, que é baseado no chromium, e funcionou normal. Vamos ver se alguém consegue reproduzir em alguma condição específica. Se puder testar com outros browsers, é um bom tira-teima (e uma conferida se acontece o problema com outras tags acentuadas também)

Comment: @Bacco Foi um problema mesmo que foi parar á página de destaque. Isso só aconteceu uma vez... Deve ser um problema dificil de voltar reproduzir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao clicar na tag ela está a ir para as perguntas com destaque, no meu caso. (nao sei porque, pode ser importante investigar). Como nao existem nenhumas perguntas com destaque neste momento com essa tag, aparecem 0 resultados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Este é mesmo o comportamento normal do site. Deverá eventualmente ser marcado como status-intencional.

> O site lembra a última subseção que você acessou. Se a última lista de
>   posts que você acessou estava filtrada para perguntas com destaque, a
>   próxima listagem que você pedir vai automaticamente para a mesma
>   subseção [@bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)

> Ou podem sempre arranjar uma alternativa melhor. Por exemplo se nao houver perguntas com destaque mostrar as mais recentes

Comment: O site lembra a última subseção que você acessou. Se a última lista de posts que você acessou estava filtrada para perguntas com destaque, a próxima listagem que você pedir vai automaticamente para a mesma subseção.

Comment: @bfavaretto Está desvendado o mistério entao.

Comment: O curioso é que isso que vc pos no spoiler foi exatamente o que aconteceu aqui no dia que vc postou. Eu cheguei a por na aba destaque e fazer a pesquisa, e mesmo assim não ficou na de destaque.

Comment: @Bacco Consegui reproduzir o acontecimento de forma consistente. Vá nas perguntas com destaque. Clique numa das tags das perguntas. Vá a página de uma tag que nao faca parte da lista de tags. Resultado 0 perguntas na aba de destaque.